# Convert an array of objects to array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON Array

```
var myObj = [{
  1: ['one'],
  2: ['two'],
  3: ['three']
}];
```

I want to convert this to an array like below

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: Ok, show us what you've tried and we'll help if we can

Comment: Also, some helpful notes here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that object keys have no guaranteed order, I'd get all the entries, sort them on the index, and them map them to the first index of their values.

```js
var myObj = [{
  1: ['one'],
  2: ['two'],
  3: ['three']
}];

var myArr = Object.entries(myObj[0])
  .sort(([k1, _], [k2, __]) => k1 - k2)
  .map(([_, [v]]) => v);

console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it in jquery-

```js
var myObj = [{
  1: ['one'],
  2: ['two'],
  3: ['three']
}];

var res = [];
$.each(myObj[0], function(index, value) {
  res.push(value[0]);
});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(myObj[0]).map(item => myObj[0][item][0])
```

Comment: adding some explanation to your answer will help you get vote ups as it would help others to understand why to use your code

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam just making readable codes :)

Answer (score 0):

While object's keys with stringed integers are sorted by their value, you could take just the values and concat an array.

```js
var array = [{ 3: ['three'], 1: ['one'], 2: ['two'] }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(...Object.values(o).map(([a]) => a)), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObj = {
  1: ['one'],
  2: ['two'],
  3: ['three']
};

var array1 = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

  var j = myObj[i];
  array1.push(j);

}
console.log(array1);
```

> If Your Object parameters are numbered u can do that, if not try to arrange it in to some kind of order so u can loop it

hope it works